# VBA Finding Values in one Array Using Another Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 arrays.

1. Array1 is a list that includes 3 columns.
2. Array2 is a list that contains 2 columns.
3. Columns 1 and 2 of both arrays have the same information.

I need to figure out how to create a third array that contains the 3 columns in Array1 and only contains items that belong to Array2.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can create the third array as, for instance, `Dim Array3() As Variant` and then as you want to add new items to it, just `ReDim Preserve Array3(1 To x, 1 To 3)` (where `x` is a variable containing how many matches you have found to date)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

Assumes your arrays are in `A1:C10` and `E1:F10` , pls change to suit.

```
Sub Arid()
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim Z

Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngCnt2 As Long
Dim lngCnt3 As Long

X = Range([a1], [c10]).Value2
Y = Range([E1], [F10]).Value2

ReDim Z(1 To UBound(X), 1 To 3)

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    For lngCnt2 = 1 To UBound(Y, 1)
        If X(lngCnt, 1) = Y(lngCnt2, 1) Then
            If X(lngCnt, 2) = Y(lngCnt2, 2) Then
                lngCnt3 = lngCnt3 + 1
                Z(lngCnt3, 1) = X(lngCnt, 1)
                Z(lngCnt3, 2) = X(lngCnt, 2)
                Z(lngCnt3, 3) = X(lngCnt, 3)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```